# What kind of diode is this? Marked "1934 MZ"

Tags: diodes, identification, surface-mount

My drone's power distribution board heated up.

There is a diode in the picture - I could not identify it.

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Alien technology. First time I have found a thing that is not on google.

Comment: 1934 is probably the date code - made in the 34th week of 2019.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a [1SMB51AT3 TVS diode](http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/datasheet/1/s/1smbxxat3_on.pdf) rated for 51V with a current rating of 7.3 amperes.

[image]

The housing size and shape match, as well as the position of the codes as seen in the linked datasheet.

Comment: Thank you so much !